# Windows Mobile Emulator networking to host machine

Tags: windows-mobile, networking, emulation

I'm trying to do some Windows Mobile dev in VS2008. The WM app is making a WCF call (or trying to). The emulator and my WCF server are running on the same desktop PC.  I found some details about how to configure the network card on the WM5 emulator in conjunction with Virtual PC2007. This does allow me to now surf the net view the emulator, which puts me a lot closer than I was. However, I can't get it to recognise the desktop machine itself, e.g. http://mycomputername/ and http://10.1.1.2/ Obviously, this makes it a bit hard to test the WCF side of things. Have I missed something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately this turned out to be a problem with my virus scanner. who knew it had a damn firewall as well...

Answer (score 4):

In visual studio that you are doing win mobile development from, go to tools menu then select device emulator manager.  If your device emulator is running you will see it with a small arrow in the list.  Right click this emulator and select "cradle".  This should open activesync for XP or windows mobile device center for Vista or higher.  Once you have cradled the emulator you should be able to access your local PC by IP or name.  Good luck, i've spent way too much time messing with trying to get this to connect so I hope this gets you there a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

After cradling in the device manager, I had to do the following:

In ActiveSync, go to File>Connection Settings from the menu, check the "Allow connections to one of the following" box, select DMA in the following combo and press the connect button

Answer (score 0):

Forget 'http://mycomputername/' for now as that could be a DNS problem. Can you ping from your host to your guest VM? Can you ping the other way? (use eg. PocketPing)

Is the WCF server listening on the IP address that the host has bound to the network device the guest VM will be using? Is that network connection set up on Windows Mobile as connecting to "Work" or "The Internet"?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this turned out to be a problem with my virus scanner. who knew it had a damn firewall as well...