# Connect to SQL Server from Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I can connect to SQL Server on my PC from a Windows Mobile device connected to the PC via USB without any problem. But I can't do the same from the emulator.

It throws an exception:

> *SQL Server does not exist or access denied.*

The connection string is:

```
Data Source=172.16.6.114; Initial Catalog=Barcode; User ID=sa; Password=123
```

What could be a problem? There is not much information in internet :(

Comment: Did you check the network connection of the emulator?

Comment: Yes, there is not network connection. And i have tried almost everything, but not helped. :( I have tried this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexdan/archive/2009/08/25/enabling-network-connectivity-on-a-windows-mobile-device-emulator.aspx

Comment: This post helped me getting the network working on the emulator: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466770/windows-mobile-emulator-networking-to-host-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when connect emulator (connect AND dock), ActiveSync or WMDC should make a connection to your PC.The sql command requires an Internet connection. Check the connection settings in ActiveSync/WMDC for the cradled Emulator (needs DMA choosen as allowed connection type in WMDC, see "Allow connections to one of the following").
[image]

Change the option "This PC connects to" to Internet or Automatic (just toggle between Internet and Automatic if it does not work) in WMDC-Connection Settings.
[image]